# Markov inequality when r-th momentum of $x$ exists.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, advice

Thank you for taking the time to read my post. I greatly value any advice you might be able to provide.

I've recently learned about Markov inequalities in my probability and statistics course.

**$P\left(\left|X\right| \geq k\right) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\left|X\right|^r\right)}{k^r}$**

This is my question

Assume that the rth moment of x exists for every positive real number r. In this case, which value of r should I select to establish an upper bound?

I apologize if my English is not perfect; I'm still learning. If there are any parts of my questions that are unclear, please feel free to let me know. I appreciate your understanding and patience

Comment: Markov’s ineqıality says that you can take $r=1$. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality

Comment: @Levent Ah, I see now. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: you can pick the best $r$, i.e. $P(|X|\geq t) \leq \inf_{r>0}\frac{E|X|^r}{t^r}$ If you have the stronger condition that the moment generating function exists, then you can deduce stronger bounds, see e.g. subexponential random variables, subgaussian random variables, and chernoff bound

Comment: Though do note that even in this case where the mgf exists, the bound on the moments is still tighter than the chernoff bound. (see for example, exercise 2.3 of Wainwright's high dim stats). As for why the chernoff bound is used much more, I can only guess

Comment: As an example, if you know $E[|X|]=\mu$ and $\text{Var}(|X|)=\sigma^2$ so $E[|X|^2]=\mu^2+\sigma^2$, then  for $k >\mu$ you can use Markov's inequality to say $P\left(\left|X\right| \geq k\right) \le \min(\frac \mu k, \frac{\mu^2+\sigma^2}{k^2})$ with the choice changing at $k=\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu}$.  Other methods can combine the different moments, often with tighter bounds: e.g. for $k$ above that point, a one-sided version of Chebyshev's inequality (Cantelli's inequality) would give  $P\left(\left|X\right| \geq k\right) \le \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+(k-\mu)^2}$.